# How to debug a nutc_driver.exe Error : ILT0005 when building a UWP app in Release Mode with Net Native tool chain

Tags: uwp, .net-native

When building my UWP in Release mode with .Net Native tool chain I have the Following error:

`Error : ILT0005: nutc_driver.exe […] returned exit code -1073741819`

There is no other error message whatsoever so I feel clueless to try and solve that problem.
How can I gather information about the problem?
What could it be and how to verify?

Notes:

`Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform` is on version  6.2.8

It builds fine in Debug mode with Net Native tool chain checked

I don't think it's an out of memory issue as I have `<Use64BitCompiler>true</Use64BitCompiler>` and the build agent has 14Gb of RAM

Comment: If you comment the default runtime directive `<Assembly Name="*Application*" Dynamic="Required All" />` in the Default.rd.xml file under Properties and build it again, will the same issue occur? There is a [similar thread](https://github.com/dotnet/corert/issues/7408), you can check it.

Comment: Tks for the link. It says to add what you suggest when the app is too big (exit code 2) to ignore some code. I dont have exit code 2.

Comment: You can choose Tools->options->Projects and Solutions->Build Run, and change the **MSBuild project build output verbosity** and **MSBuild project build log file verbosity** to **Detailed**. Then build it again. You will receive more detailed information in Output, please provide the error information for us. If the error is too long, you can put them in a file and provide it.

Comment: I work on the .NET Native compiler. That exit code in HEX is (C000 0005) which maps to access violation. Would you be able to send me a repro? I can be reached at dotnetnative@microsoft.com.

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you resolve this?

Comment: I stopped building with .net native. It builds in a few minutes rather than more than an hour. At the end no user saw any differences in terms of app performance so what's the point to use it?

Comment: Got the same error code, any news on the resolution?